# ValueError('Only know how to handle PNG; with Pillow ' 'installed, Matplotlib can handle more images')

Tags: python, arrays, image

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to load a series of images as an array.  All of the images are in the same folder.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from matplotlib import image, pyplot

loaded_images = list()
for filename in listdir('UFO-120/train_val/lrd'):
    # load image
    lr_train_data = image.imread(filename, format='JPG')
    # store loaded image
    loaded_images.append(lr_img_data)
    print('> loaded %s %s' % (filename, lr_train_data.shape))
```

Here's the entire error message.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-81fe8e3a7102> in <module>()
6 for filename in listdir('UFO-120/train_val/lrd'):
7         # load image
----> 8         lr_train_data = image.imread(filename, format='JPG')
9         # store loaded image
10         loaded_images.append(lr_img_data)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in imread(fname, format)
1462             raise ValueError('Only know how to handle PNG; with Pillow '
1463                              'installed, Matplotlib can handle more images')
-> 1464         with Image.open(fname) as image:
1465             return pil_to_array(image)
1466     from matplotlib import _png

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
2807 
2808     if filename:
-> 2809         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
2810         exclusive_fp = True
2811 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'set_o406.jpg'
```

The error seems to be telling me that all of the files need to have the .png file extension, but I thought using the matplotlib image.imread would resolve that.  I also added the format='JPG' declaration but that didn't make a difference.

As to the File Not Found Error, 'set_o406.jpg' is a valid file name in the folder.

The folder does contain 1500 images and 'set_o406.jpg' is # 754/1500, is it possible that I'm exceeding the memory that can be loaded into a single array?  If so, can you recommend a way to work around that?

I'd appreciate any help you're able to provide.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the code and found the issue. So, i made some modifications to your program according to that :-

**1st Modification**:-
Added path of your directory to a variable **imgDir**.

**2nd Modification**:-
Replaced **filename** with **imgDir+filename**. So, your program can find your file. you cannot find the file without the path of its directory.

**3rd Modification**:-
You have made a silly mistake, instead of writing

```
loaded_images.append(lr_train_data)
```

you wrote

```
loaded_images.append(lr_img_data)
```

So, finally your code looks like this:-

```
import os
from os import listdir
from matplotlib import image, pyplot

imgDir = 'UFO-120/train_val/lrd/'

loaded_images = list()
for filename in listdir(imgDir):
    # load image
    lr_train_data = image.imread(imgDir+filename, format='JPG')
    # store loaded image
    loaded_images.append(lr_train_data)
    print('> loaded %s %s' % (imgDir+filename, lr_train_data.shape))
```